# How to *only* print class shared variables?

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
class Dummy(object):
  SHARED_0 = '0'
  SHARED_1 = '1'

printOnlySharedVariablesValues(Dummy)
```

What I would like to be printed is:

```
{'0', '1'}
```

I tried:

```
class Pass(object):
  pass

set(Dummy.__dict__) - set(Pass.__dict__)
```

Which yields:

```
set(['SHARED_0', 'SHARED_1'])
```

No biggie. Using those keys I can get the values. However I consider this somewhat hacky and not elegant.

My questions is:
**What is the best way to print ONLY class shared variables in Python?**

I want to point out, that the answer provided here: [How can I get only class variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521710/how-can-i-get-only-class-variables) does not satisfy me, it is even hackier than my solution.

Comment: I think the first way is fine — and likely one of the best solutions you're going to find.

Comment: First of all, you have to provide a *precise* definition of what you mean by "class shared variables".

Comment: You should define clearly what you mean by "hacky".

Comment: I would be interested in the background of the question. E.g. why would you want to do this?

Comment: In a way, it's a weird question - you have defined the variables yourself, so you should already know what they are. If you must retrieve them, don't be surprised if the methods to do so are a bit "hacky".

Comment: try the `getmembers()` function of `inspect` module

Comment: Any item in the class `__dict__` whose key doesn't start with an underscore is public if that's what you mean by "shared". I'd also like to know *why* you want to know this because it might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to print class attributes that are not private (not starting with an underscore) and the values are not a class method type.

```
class Dummy(object):
  SHARED_0 = '0'
  SHARED_1 = '1'

print({v for k, v in Dummy.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith("_") and not isinstance(v, classmethod)})
or 
print({v for k, v in vars(Dummy).items() if not k.startswith("_") and not isinstance(v, classmethod)})
```

Output

```
{'0', '1'}
```

By iterating over the items in the class `__dict__` or the `vars()` of the class.